# How to find if child window is opened or not

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, timer, telerik

I have a requirement where I need to check whether any records have changed, depending on that I need to alert user. 
So using timer for every 5 sec I am trying to verify from database and showing alert window to the user. working great.

the problem is that, if the user stays idle for a long time. I am getting multiple alert windows as time pass on.(considering data changes for every 2 sec).

So I need to know if the alert window is already opened, How can get the instance of the opened window where I can either do some operation on it.

Here I don't want to create any single instance. Please let me know if there is any way directly can be done in silverlight.

Comment: I'm not familiar with silverlight but could you attach an event handler to the alert that sets a page variable when the user acknowledges that alert window?  Before opening a new alert check the variable to see if it's been acknowledged?

Comment: As you said you are showing alerts after every 5 seconds, are using thread for this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Telerik windows (because question is tagged Telerik), try

```
RadWindowManager.Current.CloseAllWindows();
```

Or if you need to have more control, you can iterate thru the currently open windows using

```
RadWindowManager.Current.GetWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your child window as a singleton in your application (declare private member) then open and close it accordingly and make sure to release your instance (equals to null). With that in place you just have to check if your "subwindow" is different from null that means it is open if not then you create an instance and open it.

Comment: I don't want to create single instance.sorry I should have mentioned it my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate through Application.Current.Windows(includes all windows created by your application). You can either find your alert window there and bring it to foreground or create new one.

Comment: we don't have Application.Current.Windows Option. yours doesn't work.